# How to destroy an idToken in firebase-admin?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to stop a nodejs server operation using firebase-admin, I am not using firebase-functions because it doesn't fit my requirements

I have successfully created an idToken and verified it in the server using the firebase code.

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

The problem is that when I logout on the client the `idToken` is still live for the remainder of the 60 minutes lifetime.

How do I destroy an IdToken so the server operation stops working?

Comment: There's no way to invalidate an ID token from an SDK as far as I know. What is the server operation you're trying to cancel by revoking the token?

Comment: It's a mongodb call via aws lambda/api-gateway, ideally I would like to invalidate the idToken on logout to enable me to have a "unauthorised" flag if the http request was made with the last idToken at logout or any previous idTokens if a refresh was forced. I tested previous idTokens after a refresh and they are still valid idTokens until they expire chronologically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to invalidate/revoke an ID token. You will have to implement this unauthorized behavior in some other way. Perhaps you can set a value in Firebase database at logout, and look for it in subsequent calls. For completeness, here are some previous discussions on this topic:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/hPNd5-RNgBs
[How to revoke an authentication token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560336/how-to-revoke-an-authentication-token)