# Firebase still retrieving authData after deletion

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

After I manually deleted the account connected to the uid that my iphone simulator is on (from firebase dashboard), when I run the code below it's somehow still authenticating and retrieving a uid. How is this possible?

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "https://moviebuffapp.firebaseio.com/")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if ref.authData != nil {

        let uid = ref.authData.uid
        print(uid)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Deleting an account does not automatically expire the current session(s) for that account. Their current sessions will remain valid until they expire. You can set the session expiration interval in your Firebase Dashboard.

If you want to [force the user to be logged out](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-logout), call `ref.unauth()`.

But in general you'll likely want to build authorization rules to prevent such users with valid tokens from deleted accounts to make changes to the data.

If you keep the user profiles in your database, you can check whether that record still exists in your security rules: `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()`.

Also see:

- [Firebase authentication not revoked when user deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377172/firebase-authentication-not-revoked-when-user-deleted)
- [Deletion of User in firebase does not trigger onAuth method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784421/deletion-of-user-in-firebase-does-not-trigger-onauth-method)

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to talk about how Stack Overflow operates, please post a question (or search first) on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.