# Why firebase user still signed in after I deleted it from firebase dashboard

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I used Firebase Quickstarts for Android Auth sample, Then I created a user in firebase dashboard to login the user with email and password, the user logged in successfully.
But when I deleted the user, it still logged in and showing the old user's email from (user.getEmail())

```
// [START auth_state_listener]
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getEmail());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(user);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    // [END auth_state_listener]
```

No users in my firebase dashboard and the AuthStateListener indecate that the user is signed in.

how could that be possible ?

Comment: Deleting a user account does not expire their session. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960546/firebase-still-retrieving-authdata-after-deletion/35961217#35961217

Comment: How can we delete a signed in user session then ? Guess i have that session problem here in my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43983867/7004388)

Comment: hey did you find any way?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a user from the Firebase dashboard, the user is not immediately signed out of your app. If the user is active in your app, they will be automatically signed out after a short delay. If you want to sign the user out, you will need to invalidate their session token.

The following code can be used to invalidate a user's session token in Firebase:

```
 firebase.auth().signOut()
```

I hope it would be helpful.