# Android Firebase Facebook Auth - Deleted UID still registering in app

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having an issue.  I'm currently testing Facebook auth on two devices.  Whenever I go to Firebase console and delete a user from the authentications section, the old UID is still registering in the auth state listener when logged and not allowing me to create a new user, bypassing the signup activity needed to register a new facebook user.

Does anybody know why this is?  Why my firebaseAuth isn't null after signout/user deletion?  Does it take a while to finalize or something?

Comment: Deleting a user does not expire their short-lived token, so their sign-in session may continue for up to an hour. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960546/firebase-still-retrieving-authdata-after-deletion/35961217#35961217

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen thank you!