# firebase user token revoke or logout from admin sdk

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using firebase client sdk to login with signInWithEmailAndPassword method on my server now I also want to unauth/logout user from the server (admin sdk) code. I tried following code but the old token is still working. What can we do? does the custom token will work in this case ? Basically I want to manage user login and logout on my server rather depend on firebase client sdk

```
FirebaseAdmin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
  .then(() => {
    return FirebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(uid);
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    return new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime() / 1000;
  })
  .then((timestamp) => {
    //return valid response to ios app to continue the user's login process
  });
```

Comment: You can't logout a user via the admin SDK like it's pointed out by Frank van Puffelen in this post. But there is also a workound that seems to work I guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087895/how-to-force-logout-firebase-auth-user-from-app-remotely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force logout firebase auth user from app remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087895/how-to-force-logout-firebase-auth-user-from-app-remotely)

Comment: I am not user firebase store or db i just want to use auth system in nodejs

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I am using nodejs sdk and not using any firebase database or storedatabase

Comment: When an ID token is minted it gets a certain expiration data (default is one hour) There is no way to revoke an already minted token before it expires. That's why developers with your use-case will typically implement a lockout system in the backend they are trying to protect. In the example Constantin linked that is a Firebase database, but you could implement the same in other systems too. What isn't possible however is kicking a specific user out of Firebase Authentication before their ID token has expired.