# How to logout / signout from firebase auth with python flask

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-authentication, logout

I am Creating a simple login, logout, signup flask web app using firebase auth and I successfully created login and signup but stuck in logout. So is there any way to log out or sign out from firebase auth?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to invalidate a specific token, however you can invalidate the refresh token [(refer this article)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients)

But that doesn't seem to be your problem. So, Simply the best way to go about this would be to delete the token or forget the user from client side :

```
auth.current_user = None
```

After the user is set to None, the requests will not be authenticated and hence it's more like the user has logged out.

Still, if you want to implement this for some specific case, there is a workaround you can [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087895/how-to-force-logout-firebase-auth-user-from-app-remotely)

Comment: @ParthNath Great! Then you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in with firebase, it typically gives you a refresh token and an id token. These are JWT's that identify the user and the other refreshes the id token when it expires as the id token expires after 1 hour.

If you are using something like PyreBase
`auth.current_user = None` is not secure.

Instead, you should look at the sign out method provided.

```py
import pyrebase

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
auth = firebase.auth()
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,password)
auth.signOut()
```

Comment: I tried like you said auth.signOut() but it gives me an Attribute error "Auth object has no attribute signOut"