# Firebase Auth getCurrentUser() retrieves a deleted user

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Hello and thanks for your time.

I've been working on an android app using Firebase.

I've set up Firebase Authentication and the user can register with email and password and log in after email verification.

When the app opens, I check if the user is still logged in with the `onStart()` method, but I tried that after deleting the user from firebase and I could still log in!

Should I be checking this in another way?

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}
```

---

******************************************* UPDATE *********************************************

Fixed the problem using [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)
, but then I split the signIn and createAccount methods into 2 separate activities With that I also separated the `createAccount()` from `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` methods which made me add this `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` in both activities `onCreate()` method. In the logIn activity I added

`mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                ...
            }
        };`

but now doesn't work. Am I forgetting something or just can't do this?

Here's the code I found relevant:

LogInActivity class onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

    // Views
    emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.pswdEditText);

    // Buttons
    findViewById(R.id.logInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.forgottenPaswdTextButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.registerTextButton).setOnClickListener(this);

    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Check for user connection
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + currentUser.getUid());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            updateUI(currentUser);
        }
    };
}
```

SignInActivity class onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    // Views
    emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.pswdEditText);
    passwordRetypedEditText = findViewById(R.id.pswdRetypeEditText);
    nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);

    // Buttons
    findViewById(R.id.signUpButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.logInTextButton).setOnClickListener(this);

    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}
```

Comment: Have you sccessfully signed out before?

Comment: Havn't tried, but if I clear app cache and stuff it will disconect the user. Just won't detect he doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: @PedroMarques you forgot to add listener like `addAuthStateListener(AuthStateListener)` and then remove it in `onDestroy()` like `removeAuthStateListener(AuthStateListener)` to register or unregister listeners.

Comment: Well...i just completely missed that. Probably when I changed things up! I'll see how it goes but thank you very much for all the help!!! @JeelVankhede

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: oh and by the way! Do I have to add it either in the logIn activity and the signIn? In my app the launcher activity is the login one and then, if the user doesn't have an account it changes it to the sign in activity. Btw is there any way to rate users in here? @JeelVankhede

Comment: You can add listener in Login Activity as it's your launcher activity and handle redirection accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I reopen the app after deleting the account it doesn't notice the account is gone...

I have the "mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged()
on my onCreate() and
"mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);"
on my onStart(). Am I missing something??

Comment: Well I guess I just found out...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961217/5909648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to **[AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)** for `FirebaseUser`'s state changes.

**Why?**, basically when you remove user from server or other device, it would still be valid in your current device because of it's token is not refreshed yet locally.

Find out about more **[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).**

---

Doc states that:

> There are some cases where **`getCurrentUser`** will return a **non-null** `FirebaseUser` but the underlying token is not valid. 
>   This can happen, *for example*, if the user was deleted on another device and the local token has not refreshed. 
>   In this case, you may get a valid user **`getCurrentUser`** but subsequent calls to authenticated resources will fail.
>
> **`getCurrentUser`** might also return **null** because the auth object has not finished initializing.
>
> If you attach an `AuthStateListener` you will get a **callback** every time the underlying token state changes. This can be useful to react to edge cases like those mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll add that and see if it solves the problem!

Comment: I had the problem solved with your answer, then decided to separate the login and register in 2 activities. With that I also separated the createAccount() from signInWithEmailAndPassword() methods which made me add this "mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()" in both activities onCreate() method. In the logIn activity i added mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
@Override
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
 FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
  ...
 }
}; but now doesn't work. Am I forgetting something or just can't do this?

Comment: Can you share the code in OP? I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: OP? I'm sorry I'm not getting there o.o'

Answer (score 2):

For me, **AuthStateListener** didn't help me anymore. So I used work around, I removed the user from the realtime database and then I checked if he exists or not, If not then **sign out** like that:

```
DatabaseReference dbUsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

dbUsersRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@com.google.firebase.database.annotations.NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                
                // user has sign out 
            } else {
                // user still logged in
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like firebase saves user preferences locally try to clear the app and login again check this document [FIREBASE USER AUTH](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)