# Firebase Authentication session does not expired

Tags: authentication, flutter, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Authentication for login and sign up in my app.

It works fine but problem is when I delete a user manually from the Firebase Authentication page then open the app the user i deleted still logged in.

Aren't there any way to fix this problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377172/firebase-authentication-not-revoked-when-user-deleted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784421/deletion-of-user-in-firebase-does-not-trigger-onauth-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably due to you using Access Token and Access Token is still valid even though you deleted user. To avoid that problem easy fix would be when you start app try to Refresh Access Token.

You should also look into how long token is valid.. Maybe try to shorten expiration time.