# notify application directly when you delete a user in the firebase console?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to notify the application directly if you delete a user from firebase using the firebase console? I have tried with an authlistener but the application does not notice the change in current user when I delete the user. I have to reinstall the application for the application to notice that there is no user anymore? Is there a way to solve this?

What I have tried

```
override fun getFirebaseAuthState() = callbackFlow {
    val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
        trySend(auth.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.checkIfUserExists().addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
       awaitClose {
         auth.checkIfUserExists().removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
       }
}
```

The viewModel calling it

```
   init {
        getAuthState()
    }


    fun getAuthState() = liveData{
        useCases.getAuthState().collect{response ->
            emit(response)
        }

    }
```

Comment: This code was inspired by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8). However, it doesn't handle the case when you delete a user from the Firebase console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication state on the client is based on an ID token, that is valid for one hour and automatically refreshed by the SDK. When you delete (or disable) the user, the client can no longer refresh the ID token, but its current ID token will be valid for up to an hour.

You can force the client to try and refresh its token before that, but Firebase has no built-in way to immediately notify the client of the (so-called out-of-band) user deletion.

If you want to mark the user's ID token is having become invalid, have a look at the Firebase documentation on [ID token revocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation) or one of these questions:

- [When a Firebase user is deleted from Firebase console (after user login), it is not reflected in the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956709/when-a-firebase-user-is-deleted-from-firebase-console-after-user-login-it-is)
- [Firebase authentication not revoked when user deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377172/firebase-authentication-not-revoked-when-user-deleted)
- [Why firebase user still signed in after I deleted it from firebase dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733576/why-firebase-user-still-signed-in-after-i-deleted-it-from-firebase-dashboard)
- [Deletion of User in firebase does not trigger onAuth method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784421/deletion-of-user-in-firebase-does-not-trigger-onauth-method)