# How to inform user when admin deletes him manually from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Swift 4. I am deleting the users from Firebase console manually and want to know, how can I inform the users about the backend changes that I make like disabling, deleting a user. How will the user know?

Of course, the user will not be able to log in, but is there any better way around to inform the users?

Comment: Consider using a custom flag that indicates that the user is inactive instead of deleting a user altogether.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though: what are you trying to accomplish by deleting their account?

There is no event that is triggered when you delete a user account. Deleting user accounts should be **very** rare, because it doesn't really accomplish anything. Next time someone signs in with the same credentials, it will just create a new account for them.

If you're trying to prevent the user from accessing specific backend resources, then you should probably add a flag (e.g. `disabled: true) to their profile, or keep a list of "banned UIDs" in your database. For an example of this, see:

- [How to set Firebase Database rules? How to prevent .write from deleted user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195656/how-to-set-firebase-database-rules-how-to-prevent-write-from-deleted-user)
- [How to disable Signup in Firebase 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357554/how-to-disable-signup-in-firebase-3-x/38357717#38357717)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an observer to the userID in firebase , if at any point in time the dictionary data of it is nil , then it's deleted

```
    userContentsRef =   self.ref.child("users/\(userID)")

    userContentsRef .observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        if(value == nil)
        {
          print("user deleted")
        }

     })
```

Comment: What if application is not running ?

Comment: u can inform him directly before delete by push notification or do what in answer as initial check when app opens

Comment: According to you , Whenever you get value == nil then user has been deleted are you sure ?

Comment: This answer would only work if the user is authenticated and observing the node in question. Most of the time, Rules would be in place that would prevent an unauthenticated user from accessing that node.