# ReactJS and Firebase Users Admin

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to create a React app where a user with "admin" role can create a new user in firebase.

The workflow would look like that:

```
normal login -> check userRole -> if admin: show createUserForm.
```

As far as I have read from the documentation, I would need an Admin SDK, but the problem is - how to implement it on client-side app? Has anyone gone through this process?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDK should only be used in a trusted environment, i.e. a server you control or Cloud Functions. It should not (and cannot) be used in a client-side React app.

If you want to allow certain users of your React app to create accounts for other users, you'll want to move that part of the flow to a trusted environment where you *can* use the Admin SDK.

So the flow becomes:

- Detect in the client-code whether the user is an admin (likely [using a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client)) and only show the form if they are.
- [Call a Cloud Function from your client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) with the input from the form.
- [Ensure the user calling Cloud Functions is authorized](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint).
- [Create the user account in the Cloud Function using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user).

As you can see this is quite involved. I highly recommend considering alternative use-cases, such as what it actually is that you want the admin to control. Once you enable a provider in Firebase Authentication, any user can create an account with that provider. Trying to control that from within your application code is just a recipe for problems. Often what you're actually trying to control is what a specific user account can do: e.g. only approved users can access certain data. Depending on where you store this data, that is much easier to control. For example: if you store the data in the Firebase Database, is is common to [create a whitelist of approved users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357554/how-to-disable-signup-in-firebase-3-x/38357717#38357717) in such a case (or the inverse: [a blacklist of banned users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195656/how-to-set-firebase-database-rules-how-to-prevent-write-from-deleted-user)).