# How to authenticate user email and password using Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Swift and Firebase. I am developing an IOS application. For this App I need authenticate user email and password. I have a Json file with user details. Please help me how to authenticate user email and password?I have read several posts in Stackoverflow, but I am stuck. 
Following are my Json and swift code.

Json file:

```
{
   "ID": 123,
   "Membership": 1234,
   "title": "Mr.",
   "firstname": "kumar",
   "lastname": "sandeep",
   "email": "sandeepcs2005@gmail.com",
   "membrshipstatus": "Active",
   "volunteer": "Yes",
   "creationDate": "2016-12-27 "
 },
```

This is my swift code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth



class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailofUser: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordofUser: UITextField!
    var ref:FIRDatabaseReference! //created a variable ref of type firebase database reference
    var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle? //to handle to database listener like to stop or start it



    var postdata = [String]?()
    var postall = [[String:String]]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



            //set firebase reference
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let userRef = ref.child("Hub")
        //let queryRef = userRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("mr.stefankirsch@gmx.com")


        // Consider adding ".indexOn": "email" at /hubeindhoven-95f09 to your security rules for better performance


       userRef.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue("mr.sandeep@gmail.com").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            for child in snapshot.children {

            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot

                let userDict = snap.value as! [String:Any]

                let userId = userDict["ID"]
                let lastname = userDict["lastname"]
                print("\(userId!)  \(lastname!)")


            }
                    })
```

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40762653/3108877

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you. But that does not answer my question. I already have users in JSON file and I have to validate them. How can i do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your firebase json what you have posted is wrong, are you following standard way to add user (in firebase web interface).
There is no unique id for each user. For example I have added one of mine..

```
{
  "users" : {
    “UOLTzymgIyeGgNBSS0UgUs95od21” : {
      "email" : "aaaaa@gmail.com",
      "firstName" : "aaaaa",
      "lastName" : “bbbb”,
      "mobileNo" : 12122121
    },
    “CveQ13sLmMO93yHZEAP24xHA3VZ1” : {
      "email" : "bbbb@gmail.com",
      "firstName" : “bbbb”,
      "lastName" : “bbbbb”,
      "mobileNo" : 11223333
    }
  }
}
```

---

I have added code for signin, this worked for me, hope this will solve your problem

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in
            if user != nil {
               self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UserDetails", sender: self)
            }
        }
   }

@IBAction func LoginPage(sender: UIButton) {
        FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: textFieldLoginEmail.text!,
                               password: textFieldLoginPassword.text!)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jay, Thank you for the wonderful reply. In my situation, users are already created and the data is stored in Easy dus database. So now I have to export the user details (email, passoword, name, etc,,) in CSV and convert it to JSON. Then I have to import JSON file and authenticate users.

Comment: @Jay Now I need to import JSON file to the Database and I have to validate user login. How can I achieve this? Please help

Comment: Hi Ratnesh, thank you for the excellent reply. JSON structure I posted is an example, but soon I will post the required JSON file.

Comment: Looking at your Json file I got a doubt. Where did your JSON file located,  in Database or ?

Comment: Hi all, I have changed the JSON file, that is the exact structure I am working.

Comment: Please help. how can I fetch email and ID from that JSON file?

Comment: Hi I have tried the code given by Ratnesh,but its not working. I am still trying,but no result. Can any one help me please?

Comment: @SandeepKumat Can you write your code here, so I can help, Or it is same what you have posted.

Comment: Hi Ratnesh, thank you for the reply. Below is my code

Comment: @SandeepKumat , Hi sorry for late reply, did your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues that need to be addressed.

The first one is that Firebase handles email/password authentication for you, and once a Firebase user is created, authenticating is very simple:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

An additional JSON structure in Firebase is not required. However, if you want to store additional information about each user, levering the users user id (uid) is the way to go. That uid is auto generated with when creating the user in firebase and then you can also create a separate node to contain other user info

```
users
   uid_0
     name: "Leeeeroy"
     favorite_game: "WoW"
```

Seeing as you already have users in a JSON structure, I would recommend crafting up a quick app to iterate over those users, creating their Firebase account and adding personal data to a users node.

Creating users is also simple

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

If you *really* don't want to create Firebase users, you could roll your own authentication scheme (not recommended however).